# Java connect to several SAP Systems via JCo

Tags: java, jco

I am currently developing a small Java Application which needs to read some data from SAP system.

Nearly everything is working fine, I can connect to SAP system, I can call a BAPI and get a result and I also can handle the given result.

But I have two different SAP Systems (System A and System B).

If I start my application and make a connection to System A, everything is fine. But after all data from System A are handled I want to call System B (without stopping / restarting my application). In this situation I can't connect to System B.

I think there must be something wrong with the part where I establish the connection to my SAP System.

Can anybody tell my how to do this right?

This is my Code:

This is how I make a connection (SapLogOn and SapSystem are only wrapper classes for the needed parameters)

```
private void connectToSap(ISapLogOn logOn, ISapSystem system)
            throws JCoException {

        connectProperties = new Properties();
        connectProperties.setProperty("ACTION", "CREATE");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_DEST, "POOL_DE");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, system.getAsHost());
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR, system.getSysNr());
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, system.getClient());
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER, logOn.getUserName());
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, logOn.getPassword());
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG, system.getLanguage());
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SAPROUTER, system.getSapRouterString());
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_POOL_CAPACITY, system.getPoolCapacity());
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PEAK_LIMIT, system.getPeakLimit());

        MyDestinationDataProvider myProvider = new MyDestinationDataProvider();

        if (!com.sap.conn.jco.ext.Environment
                .isDestinationDataProviderRegistered()) {
            com.sap.conn.jco.ext.Environment
                    .registerDestinationDataProvider(myProvider);
        }
        myProvider.changePropertiesForABAP_AS(connectProperties);
    }
```

And here comes part two:

```
public class MyDestinationDataProvider implements DestinationDataProvider {

    public static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyDestinationDataProvider.class.getName());
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private DestinationDataEventListener eL;
    private Hashtable<String, Properties> propertiesTab;

    public MyDestinationDataProvider() {
        this.propertiesTab = new Hashtable<String, Properties>();
        this.eL = new DestinationDataEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void updated(String arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void deleted(String arg0) {}
        };
    }

    public Properties getDestinationProperties(String destinationName)
    {
        if(propertiesTab.containsKey(destinationName)){
            return propertiesTab.get(destinationName);
        }
        LOGGER.error("Destination " + destinationName + " is not available");
        throw new RuntimeException("Destination " + destinationName + " is not available");
    }

    public void setDestinationDataEventListener(DestinationDataEventListener eventListener)
    {
        this.eL = eventListener;
    }

    public boolean supportsEvents()
    {
        return true;
    }

    void changePropertiesForABAP_AS(Properties pConProps)
    {
        if(pConProps.getProperty("ACTION").equalsIgnoreCase("CREATE")){
            propertiesTab.put(pConProps.getProperty("jco.client.dest"), pConProps);              
        }
        else if(pConProps.getProperty("ACTION").equalsIgnoreCase("DELETE")){
            propertiesTab.remove(pConProps.getProperty("jco.client.dest"));
        }
    }
}
```

I use Java 6 and JCo3.

Regards LStrike

Comment: I'm not sure it is wise to change the connection properties while the connection is in use. Have you tried to add a second connection with a different destinationName=